# Having trouble creating certain graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to create a graph which given a list of dates, will produce a line graph representing the number of occurrences of list dates. For example, this would be ideal.

[image]

But when I try to recreate something like this in Excel (2013), I get a different result and can't figure out how to change the settings to achieve the desired result.

[image]

Is this desired graph possible in Excel, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/595475/219090

Comment: @Jerry your solution is actually much better than mine, I'd upvote it also if you summarised and added it here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph you want to make is frequency and date, so you need to tabulate the frequency. To do this collect all the unique dates and calculate the frequency using [`COUNTIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx).

`=COUNTIF(range, criteria)`

[image]

When you graph this you will get the graph you want

[image]

---

**Update:** Have a look at [Jerry's answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/595517/22177). A pivot table is ideal for a large and growing set of data.